# Linker error in dev c++

Tags: c++, ide, linker

I download [this program](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/mshtml/index.html), and I add a little modification. When I compile this I see [this errors](http://pastebin.com/Q1StgzXP). I found in Internet solution, that this parameters

> -lole32 -lkernel32 -lgdi32 -luuid -luser32

help me. I add this to linker and dev c++ throw me [this errors](http://pastebin.com/MknbVHjw)

What is wrong? What parameters I must add?

Comment: It would be best to keep the question as self-contained as possible, not referencing outside links for critical information.

Comment: Sorry, bu on stackoverflow it don't look goog

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the -L parameters, to instruct the compiler where are the libraries that you specified with -l option.

If your installation of Dev-Cpp is on `C:\DevCpp` so you should add:

`-L"C:\Devcpp\lib" -lole32 -lkernel32 -lgdi32 -luuid -luser32 -mwindows`

Comment: @asd: Could you paste the complete command line you're using to compile your program?

Answer (score 0):

Errors like these mean that probably you forgot to link a library. The -l** parameters tell the compiler to link the named libraries. Googling for one of the undefined references, e.g. "SafeArrayAccessData lib", led me to the MSDN site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891243.aspx describing the function, and showed me that it is part of the library Oleaut32.lib. So maybe adding the parameter -loleauth32 will solve the problem.